# Error message When submitting to apple App store

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, itunes-app

when trying to submit my app on iTunes i keep getting this error. How do i fix it??

error ITMS-90017:  "this bundle is invaild. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named payload, containting only a. app bundle and optional plugins in a Plugins directory"

Comment: Any chance you're trying to submit an app that was built using a custom/command line tool and now contains a WatchKit app?

Comment: not sure this is my first app

Comment: What did you archive?